# Linux server performance analytics and load monitoring software

Tags: linux, performance, centos, metrics

What I am looking specifically for is software thats runs on Linux (CentOS) that can do the following:

- Show human readable CPU, Memory, Disk, Apache, MySQL utilization/performance.
- Provide historic reports on the above metrics (today, week, month, year etc...)
- Provide this data in an easy to view web based report or at least exportable to excel/csv.

I have looked at Cacti and I don't think its really an enterprise solution.  I don't care if this is free or paid for software, though open source would be nice I am really just looking for the best solution.

Does anything like this exist for Linux?  The problem this company is faced with is we have no way of measuring how the changes we make in our code and server configurations impact overall performance.  So when I saw lets do this - then do it, I can't shows the benefits or revert back cause it was a negative in terms of performance.  I am not a linux guru, just a developer with some linux skills, but am open to all suggestions.  Thanks for reading.

Comment: Shouldn't this go on http://serverfault.com/ ?

Answer (score 2):

Even though there are lot of open source projects but the main drawback they suffer is that they are away harder to configure. I have some across a free to called [SeaLion](https://sealion.com) which is way easier to install and configure. And it has awesome timeline base to representing outputs. Also there are different paid tools line new relic, server density, solar wind which you can also give a look. 
[image]

Comment: Sealion is very useful as you can add custom commands and schedule it and when problem appears you can find out what went wrong !!

Answer (score 1):

Check out the eginnovations monitoring tool

http://www.eginnovations.com

Monitors Linux, Apache, mySQL and other applications and is web-based, so you dont have to be a linux expert.

M.

Answer (score 0):

[Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/) is a simple one. [OpenNMS](http://www.opennms.org/) is more complete.

You are not limited to linux, using SNMP you can fetch this data from a remote host and use any NMS you like.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO one of the best "freemium" tools is Zenoss (http://community.zenoss.org/).

The community edition is free. It will do everything you need, and comes with a simple RPM based installation process. It's a lot easier than Cacti or Nagios to setup and use. I would give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I use [munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/). I'ts much **much** simpler to set up than cacti. It's better to compile it yourself than pull it with apt-get (or other) because that way it has more built-in data-gathering scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Basically there is no single dashboard where you can get all reports metrics. There are a range of opensource softwares which and can serve your need.

For server performance many people recommends munin, you will have to learn how to read teh report data. You can also write custom scripts to get certain report parameters of Mysql. Additionally if your server host provides an API, you can then do lot more related to reports in your admin panel.

you have a look at following url which can provide you more idea about choosing best fit to your need.

https://serverfault.com/questions/44/what-tool-do-you-use-to-monitor-your-servers
http://sixrevisions.com/tools/10-free-server-network-monitoring-tools-that-kick-ass/